# Gradle not running task in parallel for multiple subprojects

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project with multiple subprojects and have the following block of code in my build.gradle:

```
subprojects{
   task (test){
      println("START "+ project.name)
      sleep(1000)
      println("END " + project.name)
   }
}
testTask
testTask.dependsOn subprojects.test
```

I have `org.gradle.parallel=true` in my `gradle.properties` file, and am using the `--parallel` flag in my CLI call. However, when I run `./gradlew --parallel testTask`, it prints each subproject one at a time rather than printing them all in parallel, meaning it takes 1 second per subproject rather than printing them all in one second. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.